# Guardar datos en un archivo csv

Tags: ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails

Necesito guardar mis datos del base de datos de Rails en un archivo CSV.

He seguido los pasos de este post: http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

Pero al hacerlo todo tal y como lo pone ahi, al abrir en el navegador me aparece este error:

> ```
> 500 Internal Server Error
> If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's
> log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.
> ```

Este sería mi código:

El `index`, de mi controlador `Terminal`:

```
def index
  @terminals = Terminal.all

  @terminals = Terminal.order(:name)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv {render text: @terminals.to_csv}
  end
end
```

El modelo `Terminal`, con su función de `CSV`:

```
def self.to_csv
  CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << column_names

    all.each do |terminal|
      csv << terminal.validates.values_at(*column_names)
    end
  end
end
```

Y este sería la vista `index`:

```
 <% title "Enable Terminals" %>
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

 <h1><%= yield(:title) %></h1>
 <div class="menu">
 <!-- < link_to "Upload terminal list", upload_path> -->
 </div>
 <%= render partial: "terminal", collection: @terminals %>
```

Faltaria algo en la vista?

Comment: El error lo puedes ver el log del servidor en el archivo `log/development.log` o bien, en tu terminal (donde ejecutaste `rails server`) aparece el error. Comparte ese error para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que hayas agregado correctamente la librería `CSV` y no olvides **reiniciar tu aplicación** (esto es, desde la línea de comandos, cancelando el proceso actual y corriendo nuevamente el comando `rails server`).

Además, tienes un error aquí:

```
all.each do |terminal|
  csv << terminal.validates.values_at(*column_names)
end
```

En lugar de `validates`, deberías tener `attributes`:

```
all.each do |terminal|
  csv << terminal.attributes.values_at(*column_names)
end
```

---

No relacionado con tu error, pero relevante: Podrías omitir la línea `@terminals = Terminal.all` por completo, pues reemplazas su contenido una línea más abajo.

Así quedaría tu método `index`:

```
def index
  @terminals = Terminal.order(:name)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv {render text: @terminals.to_csv}
  end
end
```